# docker build with pip install overwrites existing packages

Tags: python, docker, pip

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker_with_pre_installed_packages:1.0
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD app app
WORKDIR /
```

docker_with_pre_installed_packages has:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_packages/db
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_packages/config
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_packages/logging
```

requirements.txt:

```
my_package.redis-db
my_package.common.utils
```

after running

```
docker build -t test:1.0 .
docker run -it test:1.0 bash
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_packages/
ls
__init__.py redis_db common
```

pip freeze still shows the old packages
and I can still see the dist-info directory
but when trying to run python and import something from the pre installed packages I getting:

```
ImportError: No module named my_package.config
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install python in your docker_with_pre_installed_packages or just copied some files? Looks like python was not properly installed.
By the way, Python 2.7 is not supported since this year, highly recommend to use Python 3.
Try to use python docker image and install dependencies and compare.

```
FROM python:3
ADD requirements.txt /
ADD app app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "./my_script.py" ]
```

Comment: did you try to install dependencies inside of the container one more time, i mean ssh to the container and pip install requirements, check what does it say?

Comment: if im trying to install whithin the container it works...
very strange

Comment: Seems like dependencies were not installed if it worked. Did you get any error while building docker image?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking what exactly has changed in your docker container due to executing

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I would

1) build docker container from lines before pip install

```
FROM docker_with_pre_installed_packages:1.0
ADD requirements.txt .
CMD /bin/bash
```

2) run the docker and execute manually `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Then outside docker (but having it still running) I would see what a difference the above command caused in my container by executing

3) `docker ps` to see container_id (e.g. `397cd1c9939f`)

4) `docker diff 397cd1c9939f` to see the difference

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the jenkins slave running this build.
I tried to run it on a new one and all got fixed